# Error on line that doesnt exist

Tags: php

I'm trying to define a link based of a $_GET variable, but it's saying there's an error on a line that doesn't exist...

```
 <?php

if(isset($_GET['ref'])){
    if(!empty($_GET['ref']))
    {
        $ref = $_GET['ref'];
    }
?>

<?php

      if ($ref != "") {
  $link = "http://site.com/page.php?ref=$ref";
} else {

 $link = "http://site.com/page.php";
    }

?>
```

Anyone see what's up? I was pretty sure it was fine.

I've tried it multiple different ways, with isset etc... same result.

Comment: could you post the text of the error?

Comment: which line? it's mostly the line before the one that doesn't exist :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a closing `}`:

```
if(isset($_GET['ref'])){
    if(!empty($_GET['ref']))
    {
        $ref = $_GET['ref'];
    }
}
```

By the way, this code is quite redundant. `empty()` will also check whether the variable is set, so you don't need `isset()`.

You can also use the [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary), which is for cases like this:

```
$ref = empty($_GET['ref']) ? null : $_GET['ref'];
```

And later check with:

```
if (!is_null($ref)) {
    //whatever
}
```

Otherwise, in your code, when execution reaches `if ($ref != "") {`, the variable `$ref` might not even exist - this will throw an `E_NOTICE`, which you might not even see, depending on your settings.

Comment: Also if $_GET['ref'] is NOT set then using variable $ref will also throw an error...

Comment: There are cases in which both `isset` and `empty` return true. This is (at least) the case when `$_GET['ref']` equals 0 or the empty string.

Comment: What about the link part? Any tips for doing that? it's not working atm.

Comment: @user1665256 I have already given enough clues about that in my last edit, don't expect me to write the whole thing :). Also read Arjan's comment, it is important.

Comment: I'm really quite confused by this "ternary operator" part. is this instead of the previous if statement or...?

Comment: @user1665256 Yes. I will add a link to the manual about the [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary).

Comment: Got it, everything works. Thank you!